# Highlighting a code block using viEMU

Tags: vim, viemu

May I know how do I highlight a code region say for example

```
public void foo()
{
blah();
blah1();
blah2();
}
```

where my cursor is at 'b' of first `blah()`, how can I highlight the whole code region using viEmu or VIM per se?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vim, that's `va{` (or `va}`, or `vaB` as synonyms). The `v` enters visual mode, and `a{` is a text object that selects *a Block*. If you don't want the curly braces included, use `i{` (*inner Block*) instead. And if you want to operate (e.g. delete) on the block, you can skip visual mode and just use a command that takes a motion, e.g. `da{`.